# Raw H264 NALU hardware decode on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, h.264

I receive raw H.264 NALUs from an IP camera (via Live555) and I want to decode them using hardware because FFmpeg is great but it's too slow (the camera sensor is large).

The only solution I see is to write the NALUs to some movie container file such as MPEG-4, and then read and decode that file using an `AVAssetReader`.

Am I off in the weeds? Is anyone having success decoding H.264 NALUs from a stream? Does anyone have any tips for writing NALUs to an MPEG-4 file? Other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Matt mentioned, there is no direct access to Apple's H264 decoder.

However, I have had success with ffmpeg and h264 decoding. Like you mentioned, I have built ffmpeg with LGPL I was able to decode H264 streams all the way to real-time HD stream with no latency on both ipad and iphone. Nothing fancy is required from ffmpeg, you can find bunch of standard decoding c++ code that will work just fine on iOS.  Also, in my case H264 NALUs were delivered via RTP/RTSP in real-time.

Also, if I was you I would run your app through xcode instruments to truly see where you bottleneck is, but I would be highly surprised it is in ffmpeg decoding step.. Hopefully this info helps.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that you're successfully decoding real-time HD using ffmpeg. My setup is the same -- RTSP/RTP + ffmpeg. After reading your post, I took a careful look and found that my server is sending 2144 x 1944 video at a bitrate of 1,500,000 bps. If I cut the bitrate back to 350,000 bps, nonIDR frame decoding (avcodec_decode_video2) runs in about 80 ms, and Yuv -> RGB color conversation (sws_scale) runs in about 65 ms. Those are numbers from an iPad 3. I'd appreciate hearing whether you think I could be squeezing more out of the iPad. Thanks!

Comment: Your decoding step is as fast as it gets. However, instead of using ffmpeg to peform yuv-rgb conversion, I highly recommend using opengl shaders which will offload that process to GPU.

Comment: @Aki: Did you use this in an app which Apple has approved for the App Store?

Comment: @JakobAlminde - yes, I did. The app is still in the app store. Just make sure that you comply with LGPL requirements as posted on http://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Comment: Thanks, Aki! I was mostly worried they might’ve rejected it for using RTP instead of HTTP Live Streaming.

Comment: You are safe. Several big name apps on iOS use RTP for real-time streaming for audio/video conferencing, which is different from streaming mp4 files from a server where HTTP Live Streaming comes in as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this at present. Feel free to file a radar with Apple about wanting this sort of access to the hardware decoder. It'll certainly be resolved as a duplicate :-). I assume it is for licensing reasons why they can't give this sort of access to the hardware codec.

So, you're going to have to use a software decoder. Please be aware that if you're going to ship to the App Store then you need something with a non-GPL license (unless you want to open source your app as well).

Comment: Which part can't be done? Is H.264 hardware decoding altogether not doable, regardless of whether the data is in memory or in a movie file? WRT GPL, FFmpeg can be built for LGPL licensing which is manageable in the iTMS. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry yes I just mean streamed hardware decoding. If it's in a file then you can play it and that can use the hardware decoder. Sure about LGPL but still with that it's not ideal as you have to provide linkable object files.